# Tagging a build fails in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

Am using Jenkins ver. 1.566 and subversion plugin 2.4. Am able to checkout source and build sucessfully without any problem, but when I tag it, it throws the following error:

```
Build #3

Tagging is in progress:

Tagging test-branch (rev.16428) to https:xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/tags/test-branch-3

ERROR: Failed to tag
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: OPTIONS /xxxxxx/xxxxx/branches/sri-test-branch failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:384)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1020)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getRepositoryRoot(DAVRepository.java:132)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.copyReposToRepos(SVNCopyDriver.java:194)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCopyDriver.setupCopy(SVNCopyDriver.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNCopyClient16.doCopy(SVNCopyClient16.java:440)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:65)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnNgReposToReposCopy.run(SvnNgReposToReposCopy.java:23)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnRemoteCopy.run(SvnRemoteCopy.java:227)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNCopyClient.doCopy(SVNCopyClient.java:480)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionTagAction$TagWorkerThread.perform(SubversionTagAction.java:306)
    at hudson.model.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:127)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: No credential to try. Authentication failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:37)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.cancel(SVNErrorManager.java:32)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:185)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:694)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    ... 19 more
Completed
```

HAs anyone seen this before and know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you noticed this in the error:- `No credential to try. Authentication failed`

Comment: Yes,,I noticed that... My credentials are correct and thats how am able to checkout and build successfully.. but for tagging it throws this error. I need help to fix it.